# DropDownList in .NET WebApp - Is it possible to underline one or two items in list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have been tasked to underline one or two items in a dropdown... is this possible and to have it display in IE?

Any advice, links, sample would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout the [following plugin](http://exodecreations.com/jQuery/jqDropDown.html).

Comment: I'll try it out. So far, I haven't been able to access it on my work station because it's a blocked site for some reason. I'll d/l it when I get home and will get back

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to hand roll your own javascript solution as this is not possible in the standard  html element it produces.

perhaps this jQuery plugin would do the trick: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, but not all styles work on list items:

```
DropDownList1.Items[0].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("text-decoration", "underline");
```